# How to snap Draggable's to Grid? (Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a card that is draggable, which is layered on top of a grid, and when moved, I want it to snap to the different sections of the `Grid`. I am able to create the grid with the columns and rows and also a draggable item, but I am not sure as to whether the `snap to grid` is possible with Material UI. Is there a way to do this by using Material UI and ReactJS?

If not possible with Material UI, is there another dependency I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[`react-dnd`](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about) is compatible with Material UI and lets you create a drag layer and snap to a grid.

See `react-dnd`'s basic demo [here](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/drag-around/custom-drag-layer)

And [here](https://github.com/jamesdconklin/dnd-grid) is how you can extend it to things like: snapping, grid constraints, render arbitrary child components, reordering children

Comment: I wouldn't call `react-dnd` "compatible with Material UI". Actually it's flexible enough to be compatible with every library and every display logic. It's rather useful when building a custom snap to grid layout

Answer (score 0):

I have used many drag and drop libraries but love [this one](https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd) most. You can give it a try.

There is a story book demo at https://bokuweb.github.io/react-rnd/stories/?path=/story/grid--both. I think that perfectly resolve your problem.